# C++ MEX compilation in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, mingw, mex

I am trying to use a function called edfImport (available here: http://kobi.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/edfImport)

In order to use the function, I must first run edfCompile (included in the toolkit). When running edfCompile, I get an error:

```
??? Error using ==> mex
Unable to complete successfully
```

I am running MATLAB 7.1 (R14) and have the latest version of MinGW, Cygwin and Gnumex setup for my compiler (according to the instructions on this page: http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptolemyII/ptII4.0/cygwin.htm)

I am able to compile example mex files, but I'm still not convinced that this isn't an issue with the way my compiler is setup. Any tips gratefully received. It would be nice to know if anyone else has trouble running edfCompile as well... (http://kobi.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/edfImport)

Many thanks

Edit: The error message in full:

```
In file included from edfMexImport.cpp:6:0: 
EDFFile2.h:37:39: error: 'mwSize' has not been declared 
EDFFile2.h:127:45: error: 'mwIndex' has not been declared 
edfMexImport.cpp: In function 'void mexFunction(int, mxArray**, int, const mxArray**)': 
edfMexImport.cpp:12:3: error: 'mwSize' was not declared in this scope 
edfMexImport.cpp:12:10: error: expected ';' before 'OutputDims' 
edfMexImport.cpp:48:12: error: expected ';' before 'OptionsDimN' 
edfMexImport.cpp:49:9: error: 'OptionsDimN' was not declared in this scope 
edfMexImport.cpp:51:13: error: 'OptionsDim' was not declared in this scope 
edfMexImport.cpp:51:33: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token 
edfMexImport.cpp:51:34: error: expected ';' before 'mxGetDimensions' 
edfMexImport.cpp:73:12: error: expected ';' before 'FlagsDimN' 
edfMexImport.cpp:74:9: error: 'FlagsDimN' was not declared in this scope 
edfMexImport.cpp:76:13: error: 'FlagsDim' was not declared in this scope 
edfMexImport.cpp:76:31: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token 
edfMexImport.cpp:76:32: error: expected ';' before 'mxGetDimensions' 

C:\PROGRAM FILES\MATLAB71\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'edfMexImport.cpp' failed. 

??? Error using ==> mex
Unable to complete successfully

Error in ==> edfCompile at 15
eval(sprintf('mex -I''%s'' edfMexImport.cpp EDFFILE2.cpp ''%s/edfapi.lib''', edfapiIncludesFolder, edfapiLibraryFolder));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some type definitions are missing, particularly the `mwSize` and `mwIndex` type.
Can you add the following to EDFFile2.h and try again?

just below

```
#include "edf.h"
#include <mex.h>
```

add this:

```
#ifndef mwSize
    #define mwSize int
#endif

#ifndef mwIndex
    #define mwIndex int
#endif
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Will award bounty when I'm able to.

Answer (score 1):

The MEX file has been modified to support the 64-bit "large array handling API", as described in this document:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5C27B9/

Note that this optional large variable support was first added in R7.3 (2006b), and your version is even older.  Basically, your MATLAB is too old for the API used by the MEX file.  That said, if the MEX file is simple enough, Gunther's solution might be the simple answer to "backport" the MEX file to your older MATLAB.  Functions like mxGetDimensions() now return mwSize*, but used to return int*.

So upgrade MATLAB if you can, else try Gunther's answer and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hrm, having done Gunther's solution, I receive a couple of warnings, nonetheless it compiles successfully. But... after that I try to run the MEX file and am told it is invalid (Invalid MEX file: The specified module could not be found) - even though it definitely exists. So, I tried running on a colleague's copy of MATLAB (2009b) as suggested, but this doesn't fix this second issue. I wonder if it never compiled correctly in the first place... Still, bounty goes to Gunther since he solved the issue I described in my question. May have to start another for this though...

Comment: you aren't trying to run it on the original matlab installation, are you? That could also cause problems in the first place, since it is compiled for another system. (see http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/163403 and http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-2223MW/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked inside edfCompile.m? Unfortunatlly I don't have Matlab installed on my PC, so I can only suggest you to try to compile the two .cpp files `edfMexImport.cpp` and `EDFFILE2.cpp` manually with `edfapi.lib`

Comment: I've tried that also. The error message is the same as before. I've posted it in full above now.